# Run Cron daemon on OS X 10.10

Tags: mac-osx, cron, launchd, osx-yosemite

I am maintaining some OS X 10.10 machines which require cron for various tasks (watchdog processes, /tmp cleaners, etc.). One of them has mysteriously stopped its cron daemon, and I can't seem to bring it back up short of manually running the `/usr/sbin/cron` command as root.

This isn't really maintainable; we distrust the stability of these machines enough that we have scheduled some staggered reboots in the crontab, so someone would have to `ssh` in and restart cron every time it reboots.

I have tried unloading and reloading the cron plist for launchd:

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist
```

I thought that would start it, but it did not. I then tried:

```
launchctl start /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist
```

But that also had no effect. There is still no `cron` in the process list, cron jobs aren't running, and `launchctl list` says `-   0   com.vix.cron`.

Moving away from cron to pure launchd is one way to get around this but it would require diverging our linux and mac code even further, and would require a lot of testing and frankly a lot more familiarity with launchd.

Being relatively new to OSX I have no idea where to go from here. How can I get cron to run on OSX 10.10, and to start on boot?

---

Update:

`/etc/crontab` exists as an empty file, but all users have their respective crontabs in `/usr/lib/cron/tabs`.
A grep for cron in `/var/log/system.log` turns up no results other than the `sudo cat` invoked on the crontab files.

If I run this command once again:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist
```

I get the error `Operation already in progress`.

Answer (score 1):

launchd should start cron automatically if there are any contabs - either a global crontab at /etc/crontab or per-user tabs in /usr/lib/cron/tabs/*. Note that it does not support /etc/cron.d/, so if you're putting your job(s) there it won't do anything.

If you have at least one file in the relevant place and it's still not starting, check /var/log/system.log for error messages.

Comment: There are files in `/usr/lib/cron/tabs` and `/etc/crontab` exists. `/etc/crontab` is empty but the others have entries in them. A grep for cron in `/var/log/system.log` turns up no results other than the `sudo cat` invoked on the crontab files. Trying again with `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist` gives the error `Operation already in progress`